# How should I go forward with my web service?

Tags: php, asp.net

I am creating a web service that allows people to log in and view some stats on social networks. My setup is as follows:

- on my home PC I have a large code base of C# code that scans social networks, and analyzes them, as well as puts the info into databases. All the "meat" is here.
- I have a web server that does not support C# / asp.net. Currently it is in PHP on Hostgator.

I need a way for the web service to work efficiently ie. allow people to log in and view stats. I can't use my home PC for this, so I wanted to know which is the easiest option:

- port all code to PHP, and move all databases up to Hostgator to do a proper merge of the site
- spend the time learning asp.net, rent a windows server and try my best to make everything work
- any other options that the community can help me with

I am proficient at C# and PHP, but not asp.net. What is my best option, in terms of time and money, going forward with this service?

Answer (score 1):

Have two apps that share a database.

The C# app does the work and writes up to the database hosted on Hostgator.

The PHP app provides clients the info from the db, also hosted on Hostgator.

Comment: +1 for a sound suggestion. Also as an addition, if proficiency in C# is a fact, aim to learn asp.net mvc instead of asp.net... it should be easier when not already infected with the webforms virus ^^